# Measuring Distances and Subsequent Analysis

Tags: distance, measurement

I am measuring 24 colour panels using 4 different devices.  I know the ground truth of the 24 colours - they are a MacBeth colour chart.

Measuring the 24 colours yields a matrix of measurements (24 x 4) - 4 different ways to measure, 24 colours.

I want to know: 
1) Are the measurements accurate?  How do the measurements directly compare to the colours?
2) Are the distances between the colours similar? In the case that the measurements are not the same as the ground truths, it may still be the case that it can measure distances between colour the same.

Are there any statistical approaches, or analysis that I can do to analyse this?

Can I conclude that measurement devices are better than others and appropriate for accurate measurements?

Comment: One approach is Campbell and Fiske's *Multitrait-Multimethod* which dates back to their 1959 paper *Convergent and Discriminant Validation by the Multitrait-Multimethod Matrix* (https://marces.org/EDMS623/Campbell%20DT%20&%20Fiske%20DW%20(1959)%20Convergent%20and%20discriminant%20validation%20by%20the%20multitrait-multimethod%20matrix.pdf). Although dated, it remains one of the best approaches to estimating measurement error between differing methods and, therefore, could serve as a baseline against which to evaluate more recent options suggested by other CV participants.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information.  I am going to investigate this, but I am not interested in the differences between the devices - only the measurements and the distance between measurements with the ground truths.

Comment: Also, I could not find a downloadable MATLAB toolbox for this.  Are you aware of one?

Comment: Nope, not a Matlab guy. Another thought would be to create 4 matrices of pairwise color distances like a covariance matrix. Given such a matrix multivariate methods such as MDS (*multidimensional scaling*) become possible. One output from an MDS is a *map* or 2-D plot that would express similarities (dissimilarities) in terms of proximity: the closer the colors are in plot space, the greater the similarity. Kullback-Lieber is one widely used distance metric but there are many more. Apologies for this sketchy comment.